# Why are my ggplot objects getting so large in size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-structures, tidyverse

I am trying to plot a histogram of a variable that has 17,953,026 observations. The size in MegaBytes of this data table is ~144 MB.
When I plot this data with the most basic `hist()` function in R, the plot object produced is very small in size. But when I am using ggplot2, the 'gg' object that gets created is huge - 144 MB in size (same as that of the data). This causes rendering this plot to take forever.

'pc' is the data. It has one variable 'match length' that takes values between 8 and 47. 'plot1' is the ggplot2 object, and 'plot2' is the hist object.

Here are the sizes returned by `object.size()` function in R.
pc = ~144 MB, plot1 = ~144 MB, plot2 = 2016 B.
[image]

Here is the code used to generate these plots

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data = pc, aes(x = `match length`)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 26, fill = '#d90050', color = 'white', alpha = 0.5, linewidth = 0.05) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(8,32,2), limits = c(8,32)) +
    labs(title = 'k = 10', x = 'Match length', y = 'Count') +
    theme_gray(base_size = 10, base_family = "Helvetica") +
    theme(legend.position = "top",
          plot.title = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
          axis.title = element_text(size = 8))

plot2 <- hist(pc$`match length`)
```

Here's how the histograms look:
plot1:
[image]

plot2:
[image]

Is there any way to reduce the size of this ggplot2 object, so when I'm rendering an RMarkdown or a Quarto report, it won't take forever?

Comment: Have you looked at your `plot2` object? It's a `list`, it has no graphic component to it. Your `plot1` is going to be huge because it stores the original data inside of it, so I'm inferring that `pc` is big. You can try to mimic the histogram by pre-summarizing your data and using `geom_col` instead.

Comment: (Also ditto about `plot2` - it's not an image, it's a list including the data needed to produce the graph. But where `ggplot` stores the raw data so that you could potentially modify the graph object without recreating it, adding new layers and such, `hist()` only stores the summary statistics needed to produce the histogram.)

Answer (score 4):

- `hist` (base R) returns a `list` with basic histogram attributes, it does not store raw data or anything about the graphic object itself. Once can use the return object to *recreate* the plot, but that's different from storing the graphic object itself. In this case, the size of a `list` of basic statistics will always be small.

  To get a better idea of the size of an object created by `hist`, we can record it. See below.
- `ggplot2` returns a `list`-structure that includes the raw data. This is necessary since the graphic object is rendered specially within the context. Once rendered, the graphic object does not necessarily contain the raw data (depending on how it is plotted, of course ...).

  Generally, `ggplot2`-based graphics involve a lot more "things" (theme-derived), so I expect that plots will be slightly larger. This can be controlled by the use of `theme` and other ways.

Reproducible example for comparisons:

```r
set.seed(42)
pc <- data.frame("match length" = sample(8:47, 1e6, replace = TRUE), check.names = FALSE)
head(pc)
#   match length
# 1           44
# 2            8
# 3           32
# 4           17
# 5           43
# 6           25
```

Generate plots:

```r
gg_hist <- ggplot(pc, aes(`match length`)) + geom_histogram()
gg_hist
gg_grob_hist <- recordPlot()

gg_point <- ggplot(pc, aes(`match length`)) + geom_point(y = 1)
gg_point
gg_grob_point <- recordPlot()

h <- hist(pc$`match length`)
base_grob_hist <- recordPlot()
```

Comparison of objects:

```r
object.size(pc)
# 4000736 bytes
object.size(h)
# 1840 bytes
object.size(base_grob_hist)
# 69256 bytes
object.size(gg_hist)
# 4006336 bytes
object.size(gg_grob_hist)
# 1346728 bytes
object.size(gg_point)
# 4005616 bytes
object.size(gg_grob_point)
# 104746152 bytes
```

Notes:

- while `h` is very small, its grob size is <strike>*huge*</strike> quite small, likely since it's really just a few graphic elements. (Edited, I think it was initially large because of shifting back-and-forth between this and other plots in the same dev ... odd, still working through this one.)
- the object size for both `gg_hist` and `gg_point` (an example solely to prove a point) are almost identical, they are both storing the raw data internally, so are just a little bit larger than the raw size of `pc`
- the object size for `gg_grob_hist` is much smaller than for `gg_hist` (the size of `gg_grob_point` is *huge*, not surprisingly, since we're plotting 1e6 individual points)

I think if you want to reduce the size of your rendered PDF, some thoughts:

- are there other graphic objects you're inserting that include points and/or significantly more elements?
- the default for rmarkdown rendering is to include vector-based graphics, which *look* much better in the PDF but can increase its size; you might try rendering to PNG instead (perhaps see https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-render-ggplot-images-in-png-rather-than-pdf-in-order-to-speed-up-my-compiled-pdf-document/12133)

Answer (score 3):

ggplot2 objects keep a copy of their environment, which can include your whole dataset, this is why they can become huge.

A suggested [solution](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4056#issue-636077598) is to overwrite this environment with a clean one, so for your plot1 do:

```
plot1$plot_env <- rlang::new_environment()
```

Another suggested [solution](https://github.com/combiz/scFlow/blob/9619c6c95b640b6c1e1fdbb78f58ec89d403f446/R/generic_helper_functions.R#L27) is to convert to grob and back again:

```
plot1 <- ggplot2::ggplotGrob(plot1)
plot1 <- ggpubr::as_ggplot(plot1)
```

Comment: works like a charm - I particularly like the grob conversion approach. One minor note, while ggpubr works fine, you can also use grid::grid.draw from base R